# How to change Virtuoso DatabaseFile?

Tags: ubuntu, virtuoso

I have `virtuoso-opensource-6.1` installed on Ubuntu.
It was installed on the system storage `/dev/sda1` which has only 30Go.

I need to load DBpedia-mirror on the installed Virtuoso. However, `virtuoso.db` is located on `/dev/sda1/var/lib/` as indicated in the `virtuoso.ini`:

```
... 
DatabaseFile  = /var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/virtuoso.db 
...
```

Consequently, the space will not be sufficient to load DBpedia on this disk.

I want to know if it is possible to change the `DatabaseFile` to another disk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any file which location is specified in the INI file may be relocated with a few steps --

1. Stop the instance as normal.
2. Move the file to your desired location.
3. Edit the INI file to change the old location to the new.
4. Start the instance as normal.

If you move the INI file itself, you may need to adjust the startup command (which targets the `` `pwd`/virtuoso.ini `` at time of launch by default, and may target any file by specifying it with the `-c` or `+configfile` command argument).

It is often better to move the entire enclosing folder (`/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/` in this case), as several working files which may grow substantially with use are also found here (alongside the INI file), and this way the INI and DB files (together, the basis of any instance) are kept together (simplifying filesystem-based backup and restoration, among other things).  Of course, if you do this, double check the INI file for any other hardcoded paths to `/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/` which will also then need to be changed to the new path.

---

All that said, you may prefer to move the entire `/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/` directory.  You can then simply replace the original with a symlink to the new location -- which will keep everything working as if it were in the original location -- or again, change all occurrences of `/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/` to reflect the new location.

---

And all *that* said...  Upgrading to the current [VOS Release 7.2.5.1](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSNews#2018-08-15%20-%20Virtuoso%207.2.5.1%20Released%2C%20Open%20Source%20Edition) or later is strongly recommended for all users of VOS Release 6, for many reasons.

Comment: Thanks @TallTed. Your answar was very helpfull.
Concerning the upgrad to Virtuoso7.2.5, I faced some problems during the installation of this release. The problems are about dependencies.
For example, when I run dpkg-checkbuilddeps, it indicates me that it is unable to resolve dependecis (ex: openjdk-7-jdk).

Comment: The v7.2.5 dependencies issue you describe is not appropriate within this question. I would suggest raising it on the [new OpenLink Community Space](http://community.openlinksw.com/), the [VOS github project](http://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), or the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/). Be sure to say whether you are trying to use [a prebuilt binary](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtuoso/files/virtuoso/), or trying to build from [source](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/stable/7).